# How to change the deployment URL in a sharepoint hosted app later?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2013

I downloaded [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Hello-b3ca20f3) microsoft example for a sharepoint hosted app.

When I build an app myself I can set the deployment URL. While this seems a very simple action I can't find how to change or update it later, when it is already set.

So how can I set the sharepoint URL when a project has been deployed already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be to change the SharePoint site URL in the properties of the SharePoint project in the Solution Explorer.

Another way to do this is by editing the csproj.user file like this ([source](http://davidfrette.wordpress.com/2010/03/04/changing-the-sharepoint-site-in-a-visual-studio-2010-sharepoint-2010-project/)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SharePointSiteUrl>**Your URL here**</SharePointSiteUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: "This is the easiest way to do it." - Are you sure? I can see no sign of the server url in any of the options there. Can you elaborate on how to complete it this way? Editing the csproj.user file works fine though.

Comment: msounthar doesn't mean right-click the project and select Properties, he means click the project and press F4 to get the Properties window.

Comment: @Aries51 So just "click the project and press F4"...What does "click the project" mean? I can't find this either.

Comment: @developerwjk In Visual Studio in the Solution Explorer, you can find properties of object bij clicking on it in the treeview and then pressing F4. bv. click on a folder and press F4, same goes for files and projects. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Site Url is one of the properties of the Project so the first guess would be to look under project “Properties”.So if you right click on the Project and Click on “Properties” towards the end, you will find yourself in Properties Page with a bunch of project properties but no option for Site URL in any of the tabs.For some reasons the property “Site URL” for was not included here.It was instead included in Properties Window for the project.

Properties Page and Properties Window are two separate blocks that displays project properties in the new Visual Studio. So now lets open Properties Window to Change our “Site URl” property.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/22/change-site-url-property-in-visual-studio-2012-for-deploying-sharepoint-projects/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Open the project path in Windows Explorer
2. Locate the file `<projectName>.csproj.user` (or `<projectName>.vbproj.user`)
3. Open it with text editor (e.g. Notepad)
4. Change the `SharePointSiteUrl` property
5. Save the file, and then re-open the project (by deploying)

This works perfectly for me..